# Python throws UnboundLocalError when a global variable is used in the conditional of an if statement within a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

I am getting an UnboundLocalError despite the variable being declared in the global scope. It seems as if the variable is assumed/forced to be a local variable for this specific statement.

I can't figure out why variables within if statement conditions would be treated differently. Could someone explain what's going on?

The following snippet is a simplified example of what I was trying to do:

```
In [1]:  global mock
...      mock = False
...
...
...      def foo():
...          if not mock:
...              # do stuff
...              mock = True
...
...          # do other stuff
...
...
...      foo()
```

This throws an UnboundLocalError, despite the global bool declared right above the function declaration.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-540737067cb1> in <module>()
      7 
      8 
----> 9 foo()

<ipython-input-31-540737067cb1> in foo()
      3 
      4 def foo():
----> 5     if not mock:
      6         mock = True
      7 

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mock' referenced before assignment
```

However, this snippet runs as expected:

```
In [2]:  mock = False
...
...
...      def bar():
...          return mock
...
...
...      bar()

Out[2]:  False
```

Similarly, this snippet with the variable in the body of an if statement also runs as expected:

```
In [3]:  mock = False
...
...
...      def foobar():
...          if True:
...              return mock
...
...          return True
...
...
...      foobar()

Out[3]:  False
```

I found the following article on scopes and namespaces in the docs (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) but I feel that it should work as expected based on the following,

> Although scopes are determined statically, they are used dynamically. At any time during execution, there are at least three nested scopes whose namespaces are directly accessible:
>
> - the innermost scope, which is searched first, contains the local names
> - the scopes of any enclosing functions, which are searched starting with the nearest enclosing scope, contains non-local, but also non-global names
> - the next-to-last scope contains the current module’s global names
> - the outermost scope (searched last) is the namespace containing built-in names

I was using Jupyter 4.4.0 with Python 3.6.6 and IPython 6.5.0 within Conda on Windows 10, but I am able to reproduce this behaviour with console IPython, and IDLE 3.6.0 GUI running Python 3.6.0.

Edit: Somehow the following snippet isn't affected? It seems like this is tied to updating the variable within the same. I feel like I must be missing something trivial at this point.

```
In [4]:  global mock # also works without this line
...      mock = False
...
...
...      def foo1():
...          if not mock:
...              return mock
...
...          return True
...
...
...      foo1()

Out[4]:  False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

variables are function scoped. because there's an assignment within the function to the name `mock`, all references to `mock` are attempted as "local" (they actually get compiled to a different opcode!)

you can change this by using `global mock` in the function (so the assignment and reference are forced to *global*)

```
def foo():
    global mock
    if not mock:
        mock = true
```

Note that in your first example you wrote `global mock` at the module scope -- this does nothing :)

It may make more sense to look at the disassembly directly:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def f():
...     if not mock:
...         mock = True
...
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (mock)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        15

  3           6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
              9 STORE_FAST               0 (mock)
             12 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 15)
        >>   15 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
>>> def g():
...     global mock
...     if not mock:
...         mock = True
...
>>> dis.dis(g)
  3           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (mock)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        15

  4           6 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (True)
              9 STORE_GLOBAL             0 (mock)
             12 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 15)
        >>   15 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: If you found this answer useful or the solution, click the green check mark.